# Display a decimal field as an int in Razor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

i used entity framework to get a model from my oracle database and then ADO dbcontext generator to create my classes, the problem is that the "number" fields in oracle were passed as "decimal", what i want to do is to show them in my tables like integers.

for example  i have a cshtml view with a table, and it shows

number_of_prod
    123.00

i want it to show it like this:

```
number_of_prod
123
```

maybe with [DisplayFormat .....] , but i dont know how to use it XD!..

thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply cast to an `int` on the page:

```
@((int)myDecimal)
```

You could of course also cast them beforehand. At any rate, casting will truncate any decimal places. If you need to round them then you should use `Math.Round()`.